# Why Eclipse XML Schema editor flags "form" attribute in "element" as to be false?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

Using "Eclipse Editor and Tools" 3.9.2, experimenting with namespaces in XML schema:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://a.ngong.eu/v0_0_1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://a.ngong.eu/v0_0_1" schemaLocation="a.xsd" />
    <element name="root" form="unqualified">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="elA" type="a:A" />
                <element ref="a:aEl"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

I get a failure message about *form* attribute:

```
s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'form' cannot appear in element 'element'.
```

Why shouldn't I use that attribute there to unqualify that element? Validation to that schema works fine.

Comment: Without showing the schema file, there is no way to answer this.

Comment: what is wrong with the schema file shown, nitind? The failure is flag in line 4, "form" is red underlined.